# What is the work flow for completed features in perforce streams?

Tags: perforce

I am coming from a git background and have used perforce many times in the past but only recently with the new streams. Throughout all of the tutorials, I have found they never cover resigning or deleting streams where the feature is completed and already promoted to main.

In git, once I was finished with a branch and it was merged upstream, I'd delete the branch. I know about task streams, but they seem somewhat useless when working with other devs, since it's semi-private to the workspace that created it.

Am I really supposed to keep every stream that I have? The depot and stream graph views are quickly becoming unmanageable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Task streams are exactly what you want to use; there can be any number of workspaces associated with a task stream, meaning that they can be shared between any number of users on any number of machines.

Once you're done with a task stream, "unload" it and it goes away (the modified files will stay in the depot, but files that were branched without being modified will disappear from the revision graph, and the unloaded stream will no longer appear in the stream view).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. So in general though, development steams in perforce should NOT be deleted?

Comment: In general, yes.  (The question is a little vague -- there's a difference between "deleting" all the files in a stream and "obliterating" all of them, but I'd recommend against either as general practice, for different reasons.  Deleting the stream spec is also different from either deleting or obliterating the files, and I'd also recommend against that for similar reasons that I'd recommend against obliterating the files.)